# H2 DB: is "CROSS" a special keyword used from H2 to avoid to use in a create table statement?

Tags: database, h2, in-memory-database

I am trying to create a simple table with several columns. As soon as I try to add the column "CROSS" I get the following exception:

Create table TABLE_TEST ( 
                                    CROSS                          VARCHAR2(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_1           TIMESTAMP(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_2                      TIMESTAMP(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_3                      NUMBER(17,3) , 
                                    COLUMN_4                       VARCHAR2(1) ) [42001-194] 42001/42001 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TABLE_TEST ( 
                                    CROSS[*]                          VARCHAR2(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_1           TIMESTAMP(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_2                      TIMESTAMP(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_3                      NUMBER(17,3) , 
                                    COLUMN_4                       VARCHAR2(1) ) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
Create table TABLE_TEST ( 
                                    CROSS                          VARCHAR2(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_1           TIMESTAMP(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_2                      TIMESTAMP(6) , 
                                    COLUMN_3                      NUMBER(17,3) , 
                                    COLUMN_4                       VARCHAR2(1) ) [42001-194] 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) 
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readColumnIdentifier(Parser.java:3231) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:6052) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:4302) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:364) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:319) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:291) 
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:256) 
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:564) 
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:505) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:170) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.getResult(WebApp.java:1380) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.query(WebApp.java:1053) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:1015) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:1002) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:164) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:89) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "CROSS" is a [H2 Keywords / Reserved Words](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html)